# Unable to resolve bundle because of dependency conflict for jackson.annotation in Karaf

Tags: apache-felix, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Some time while starting a bundle (`basecomponent`) I am getting the below error. It seems it is because of the two different versions of `fasterxml.jackson.annotations` . `basecomponent` bundle is using `fasterxml.jackson.annotations` 2.7.4 . `basecomponent` bundle is also using `camel-aws` which may be using `fasterxml.jackson.annotation` 2.5.0.

```
smx@root>bundle:start 277
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
    Unable to execute command on bundle 277: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle revision basecomponent [277.0] because it is exposed to package 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation' from bundle revisions com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations [284.0] and com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations [125.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  basecomponent [277.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation
  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations [284.0]

Chain 2:
  basecomponent [277.0]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=com.amazonaws)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.amazonaws; uses:=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aws-java-sdk [254.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation)(version>=2.5.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation
  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations [125.0]
```

Can some one let me know how can I get around this dependency conflict? I am using `Karaf 3.0.5` running under `Servicemix 6.1.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in Karaf [Mailing List](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Unable-to-resolve-bundle-as-it-exposed-to-package-via-two-dependency-chains-td4046973.html#a4047185). Moving to `Karaf 4.0.5` (under `Servicemix 7.0.0.M2` ) and setting `dependency=true` in `feature.xml` I am not observing the issue now.